# How can I recover my Minecraft game, after I loaded it without Biomes a plenty?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I accidentally loaded a save game without Biomes a plenty loaded in my Feed the Beast launcher (I forced an update. For somereason that disabled that mod!)

I crashed to the ground and died as my Fir Tree tree house no longer existed.

I've re-enabled the mod, but my save seems to be borked. I have most of my items (except a handful of fir logs/planks)

Can I recover the game by *forcing* the game to put the biomes back and regenerate those chunks? If not, how do I carry my items over to a new save? I imagine I can destroy everything and put it into my inventory and then save a copy of my player.dat and regenerate the world, then drop it into the right folder. If I do this, what stuff won't be stored in player.dat?

Is any of this possible? If it helps I'm on Ubuntu 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can put most things into your inventory, make a new world with the same seed*, and then copy your `player.dat`** over the new blank one in the new world.

That will work for most things, but there are some items/blocks that store data elsewhere than `player.dat`, like CC computers and Ender Pouches. The way to find these is pretty much to just dig around in the world save folder. Any folder that isn't present in a vanilla world save is worth investigating.

You can do this incrementally, too: make a safe backup of your old world, create your new world, and then copy things over a piece at a time as you discover them. Because you've got a safe backup, you can always go digging for the save data for something when you discover it missing in your new world.

---

* An easy way to recreate a world with the same seed is to just make a new folder manually, copy the `level.dat` into it, then open the new same-name-different-folder world save that appears in Minecraft as a result. It'll regenerate the world and keep all your original settings.

** At some point Minecraft switched from using `player.dat` for single player to using `players/[username].dat`, so your "`player.dat`" is probably not actually named `player.dat`. I believe this was changed when they made it so that singleplayer internally runs a multiplayer server.

Comment: I'll give his ago over pizza and report back.

Comment: There's a <player>.dat in level.dat that minecraft uses to override the <player.dat> in the root folder. I'm trying to edit the NBT tag, but the only program I can see for it is NBTExplorer which is a .exe

Comment: Having to download mono-devel (which contains mono-winforms). Loaded up NBT and started transferring inventories. Success! now to rebuild. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you restore the save game from a backup? If you're on Windows, and you have it switched on, you might be able to use Previous Versions to get your old save files back.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/previous-versions-of-files-frequently-asked-questions

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible. First of all you have world generation to consider with Biomes a Plenty and that may have some issues there. You then have Item ID's to consider when adding new/old mods to the game.

You may be able to regenerate chunks with Biomes a plenty and simply explore unexplored chunks. The chunks that aren't loaded may generate new biomes from the mod.

You could also check if there are any previous versions of the minecraft world available but chances are there are none.

An alternate, long method is to simply create a new world and then enable cheats and spawn all the items back in.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to retrieve your world after logging in without the mod you previously logged in with.
you just have to go to the start menu on your computer and type in %appdata% and open your .minecraft folder. You then have to open your saves folder and right click on the folder of the world you want to recover. click "restore previous versions" and choose how far back you want to go to restore it.
After completing these steps you can now log into your world with the mod you started with and all of your items and builds will be retrieved.
Be careful how far back you restore your file because if you go to far back you might lose some of the items you had when you logged in with the mod.
I hope this helps!! (:

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can restore the save game from a backup. I have never tried this on a mac before but it definitely works on Windows.
Hope this answers your question. (:

Comment: down vote
It is possible to retrieve your world after logging in without the mod you previously logged in with. you just have to go to the start menu on your computer and type in %appdata% and open your .minecraft folder. You then have to open your saves folder and right click on the folder of the world you want to recover. click "restore previous versions" and choose how far back you want to go to restore it. After completing these steps you can now log into your world with the mod you started with and all of your items and builds will be retrieved.

Comment: Be careful how far back you restore your file because if you go to far back you might lose some of the items you had when you logged in with the mod. I hope this helps!! (:

Comment: you can also do this with a backup folder of your world but only if the backup got messed up as well, otherwise you will be restoring previous times you logged in and made changes. (in other words, you will lose any current changes made to the world).